# open source thread script to use?

Tags: php

im building a forum and now im gonna code the thread page.

is there any open source thread script to use that resembles stackoverflow:s thread page with the actual thread, the replies and the comments? one which you could customize?

i bet a lot of users have created such scripts, would be great to not having to reinvent the wheel.

or is it a lot easier to code it yourself?

Comment: if you are downvoting me, please show the courtesy and tell me why

Comment: I didn't downvote you but 'help me find a script' questions are usually frowned upon.

Comment: Can someone tell me why "Help me find a script" is any different than "Help me find a library" when the OP clearly says he just wants to re-use code and not re-invent a wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This looks helpful](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/5400.html). You'll need to register to be able to preview / download the class and examples, but its painless. I don't think will do *everything* you want right away, but it should make the CRUD simple and let you just worry about the design. NB: It is in Spanish, but the class seems to make itself obvious.

All of the other snippet classes that I know of which would help are designed to work with various types of MVC framework.

I'd also consider editing the title of your question. Perhaps like `Seeking class to manage forum threading` , since you are just looking for re-usable code and not a ready made `script`

Answer (score 0):

I'm really new here, but Mike B is right... and you need try harder next time.
This is not community "help me googling"... but this can help you, http://qwench.net/